# .Formula property relative reference

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Need some help on this. I wonder how can I setup `.Formula` property with a relative reference.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Example()
Dim Path As String

Start = Range("T2").Activate 

For i = 0 To 3

     Path = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0)

     With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FPA")
         .Range("U2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(N2,'" & Path & "Sheet 1'!A:Q,6,FALSE)"
     End With

Next i
End Sub
```

My issue comes with `.Range("U2").Formula.` I would like to move from cell(U2) to downside cells (U3, U4, etc) as the loop goes forward. However, when I try to change it a property error appears (438). I used several methods (ActiveCell, offset, etc) but the `.Formula` property cannot support them.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: What cell does `ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0)` represent - what column/row?

Comment: @BigBen it moves from  Cell "T2" to downside (according to i-values)

Comment: `For i = 2 to 5`, `Path = .Range("T" & i).Value`, `.Range("U" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(N" & i & ",'" & Path & "Sheet 1'!A:Q,6,FALSE)"`.

Comment: thank u @BigBen it works!